# helm template from array in values

Tags: json, yaml, kubernetes-helm, helm3

i'm trying to get from an array in my values.yaml a working template i tried many thing but i always have some error does someone has an idea ?

```
values.yaml

zones: ["eu-west-3a"]
```

```
storageclass.yaml

allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
  {{- if .Values.zones }}
    values: |-
    {{- range .Values.zones }}
    - {{ . }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end -}}
```

Goal:

```
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    values:
    - eu-west-3a
```

```
Error : Error: YAML parse error on storageclass/templates/storageclass.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 15: did not find expected key
```

Edit:

This is how i fixed the problem :

```
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    {{ if .Values.zones -}}
    values: 
    {{- range .Values.zones }}
      - {{ . }}
    {{- end -}}
    {{- end -}}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: You might try running `helm template --debug`, which will still give the YAML parse error but also will dump out the rendered content.  I wonder if there might be too many hyphens in the final `{{- end -}}` and the next item in the output is running into the end of your last value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `print` function to generate a list inside a range.

```yaml
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
    {{ if .Values.zones -}}
    values:
      {{- range .Values.zones }}
      {{ print "- " . }}
      {{- end }}
    {{- end -}}
```

Comment: I got this error :


Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(StorageClass.allowedTopologies[0].matchLabelExpressions[0].values): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.TopologySelectorLabelRequirement.values: got "string", expected "array"

Comment: This is your code from above with my fixes. I believe the error comes from the `values: |-`. You could try it just with `values:`, then the result is not a string but an array.